# How to implement GIF insertion in Unity? "XYZ App doesn't support image insertion here"

Tags: unity, android, keyboard

I'm making an **Android App with Unity**, which has a **chat service** in it.

And I would like to handle s**ending images or GIFs via Gboard**.

Currently when the user selects a **TextField**, his keyboard comes up, which is let's say GBoard.

And now when I click on a **GIF or a Sticker**, it says

> *XYZ App doesn't support image insertion here*

So how could **I implement it**?

Or more precisely, how can **I define what method will be be called** in my application when the user tries to send a GIF?

Because my first thought to implement it, is like it's done in all other apps:

- every GIF would be in a **separate message**, and when the user clicks on a GIF it instantly sends a special GIF message, which will be rendered for example as an **animated texture**.

**But how could I subscribe to this event in the first place?**

Thanks in advance!